# googlemutant and leaflet problem view data

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, google-maps-api, mapping

[image]

I just create a new map with leaflet and GoogleMutan with this three CDN libriaries:

1) maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" async defer

2) unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet-src.js

3) unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js

Why the map shows me numbers above of the tiles? there some conflict from the cdn libraries?

Answer (score 5):

That's because you didn't create a new map using Leaflet + Leaflet.GoogleMutant. That's because you copy-pasted the code from https://ivansanchez.gitlab.io/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/demo.html without bothering to read it first.

Don't copy-paste code blindly. Read it, and understand what it does. In this particular case, search for and identify the map layer which is displaying the tile numbers.

Comment: Relevant username